# Программный запуск действия из контекстного меню браузера (chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, браузер

Пытаюсь реализовать автоматический перевод субтитров на сайте [Udemy.com](https://www.udemy.com/).
Вот скрипт который необходимо загрузить в консоль или в идеале сохранить в расширении
[User JavaScript and CSS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld?hl=ru) для сайта Udemy.com.

```
// переменная для сохранения нового текста субтитров
let newText = '';

// переменная для отслеживания состояния кнопки "перевод"
let transTrigger = false

// функция вставляющая перевод в субтитры
function translate() {
    let target = $('.well--container--2edq4 span');
    let source = document.querySelectorAll('p[data-purpose="transcript-cue-active"] span')[1];
    let currentText = source.innerHTML;
    if (newText !== currentText) {
        target.html(currentText)
    }
    newText = source.innerHTML;
}

// 10 раз в секунду отслеживаем изменение субтитров и меняем на переведенный текст
window.i = setInterval(() => {
    if(transTrigger){
        translate()
    }
}, 100);
    
// ждем 5 секунд для полной загрузки страницы и вставляем кнопку "перевод"
setTimeout(function () {
    let menu = document.getElementById('scroll-port--4')
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    button.style.padding = '1rem'
    button.style.width = '200px'
    button.style.borderRadius = '7px'
    
    button.innerHTML = 'Перовод';
    
    button.onclick = function () {
        if (transTrigger === false) {
            transTrigger = true
        } else {
            transTrigger = false
        }
        if (button.innerHTML === 'Перовод') {
            button.innerHTML = 'Остановить перовод';
        } else {
            button.innerHTML = 'Перовод'
        }
    }
    menu.appendChild(button)
}, 5000);
```

Для активации перевода субтитров необходимо сначала вызвать окно "*расшифровка аудио*", затем нажать на кнопку "**перевод**", но предварительно вызвать контекстное меню кликнув правой кнопкой мыши на странице и выбрать действие "*перевести на русский*".

В принципе скрипт работает и в таком виде, но для полного счастья не хватает знания как активировать действие "*перевести на русский*" программно в скрипте. Потому, что перед каждым следующим роликом приходится это делать руками.

Заранее всем спасибо.

Comment: А зачем вообще кнопка? Нельзя сразу вызвать функцию `translate`? Руками - значит кнопку нажимать или вставлять скрипт в консоль?

Comment: Конечно можно и без кнопки. Кнопка, только чтобы можно было отключить перевод. Кнопку можно безболезненно удалить из скрипта. Но и без кнопки перед каждым новым роликом необходимо руками вызывать "перевести на русский". Чтобы исключить работу руками я и ищу способ программно активировать это действие контекстного меню.

Comment: Какую работу вы делаете руками? Расскажите подробнее.

Comment: Вызываю контекстное меню кликая правой кнопкой мыши на странице и выбираю строку "перевести на русский". - Вот это действие я пытаюсь автоматизировать. Пытаюсь найти что-то типа "chrome.contextMenu.translate()". Если найду, то можно будет отслеживать изменение в div с текстом аудио и вызывать "перевести..."

Comment: В настройках браузера можно же выбрать "Предлагать перевод на русский...", а после "Всегда переводить с английского". Так не подходит?

Comment: Для сайтов написанных не на SPA это бы работало, но увы, Udemy написан на Angular'е, а это SPA. При загрузке следующего ролика меняется только часть сайта и эта часть, в том числе субтитры,  загружается на английском. Приходится опять "работать руками".

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126896/discussion-between-mirninec-and-leonid).